# SetSelectedNotebook does not work

Tags: front-end

I have a small program like this:

```
nb1 = SelectedNotebook[];
nb = NotebookOpen["data 2015 - 2018.nb"];
SetSelectedNotebook[nb1];
```

After the 2nd command the front-end switches to notebook nb. I want the front-end to return to (or rather to stay with) notebook nb1 however but SetSelectedNotebook does not do the job. I have tried all kinds of other possibilities but thus far everything failed. Can anybody help?

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work for me. Which version are you using, and on which OS and hardware?

Comment: Indeed the trouble is with SetSelectedNotebook which is not working. Ik don't get a beep or message. The OS I am using is Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.3, the hardware is a MacBook Pro (mid 2015) 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7, memory 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Comment: Do you use an initialization cell in nb?

Comment: I do not use an initialization cell in either nb of nb1.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I can't help as it works for me (Windows 10 laptop, tried several Mathematica versions). Have you tried whether the `SetSelectedNotebook` works when using `CreateDocument` instead of `NotebookOpen`? That would avoid discussions about path and content of the notebook you try to open and probably even give more indication about the nature of the problem...

Comment: Thank you and everyone for trying. Ik have indeed tried SetSelectedNotebook, without avail. However within a couple of weeks I wil get a new computer (Mac) with, of course, the latest OS. Once I have this new computer will try it again again and put a post on the results.

Comment: I do have my new Macbook OS with OS 10.14 now. It seems that SetSelectedNotebook is unstable as on this new laptop very incidentally it does work (however most of the times it doesn't). I wil put this to the attention of the Wolfram team.

Answer (score 0):

The second line won`t work.
Executing code should emit a beep (even if the file exists in current directory), then read "Why the Beep"

For example the second line should be something like:

```
nb = NotebookOpen@FileNameJoin@{$UserDocumentsDirectory,"Wolfram","Mathematica","data 2015 - 2018.nb"}
```

To find out your correct path you may use:

Menu > Insert > FilePath ...

Some path and file related commands, depending on your needs:

```
CurrentValue@"NotebookDirectory"
CurrentValue@"NotebookFullFileName"
(* more under doc "CurrentValue" *)

NotebookDirectory[]
Directory[]

(* To get some platform independance use Directory Variables in "FileNameJoin" *)

{$UserDocumentsDirectory,$HomeDirectory}

(* more *)
Names@"*Director*"
Names@"*Path"
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Why do you say so? As long as "data 2015 - 2018.nb" is on `CurrentValue[NotebookPath]` it should work, or? Moreover, if it fails how is OP having problems with keeping selection on current notebook if it is the only one?

Comment: You are right, and it works until you change directory with FileNameSetter, this changes  NotebookBrowseDirectory. Its better to define the filenames with FileNameJoin or FrontEnd`FileName, otherwise it will be always a potential source of failure. (i.e. older version with same name in a backup directory)

Comment: I am not sure we are on the same page, OP has a problem because `NotebookOpen` works and `SetSelectedNotebook` does not. Your answer aims at `NotebookOpen` though.

Comment: SetSelectedNotebook does not work??? Then nb1 has changed? First I would try it without semicolons, then I would check for hidden changes of varible "nb1" during initialization.  Without OP we will never know.

Comment: `nb1` has not changed but `nb` was opened and it is the selected one now. When OP tried to set `nb1` to be a selected one again, it failed.

Comment: Yes, during opening nb with NotebookOpen there could be changes made by the initialization cell of nb and setting nb1 to another value. How you can you be sure that nb1 didnt change, without knowing the content of  "data 2015 - 2018.nb"

Comment: I see your point, yes that is possible. I interpreted your points wrongly.

Comment: There is no initialization cell in either nb or nb1.

Comment: Back to the roots: 
1) Delete all ";"  after the commands. Evaluate again.  Was there a "$Failed" hidden?
2) Are the documentation examples for "SetSelectedNotebook" executing successfully on your computer?
3) Did you try other variable names instead of the most common : nb nb1 nb2
4) How many years experience do you have on Mathematica?